# Ansible win_robocopy - not able to set remote shared folder as source (src)

Tags: windows, automation, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I've been pulling my hair out for a week over this. I need to copy a few files from a Windows server 2016's shared folder to another Windows server 2016 instance. I'm using the following code:

```
- name: Copy Builds
      win_robocopy:
        src: '\\192.168.195.130\share\builds'
        dest: "{{ destination }}"
        flags: /e
      become: true
      become_method: runas
      become_flags: 
        logon_type=new_credentials
        logon_flags=netcredentials_only
      vars:
        ansible_become_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"
        ansible_become_pass: "{{ ansible_password }}"
```

I've verified that \192.168.195.130\share\builds is accessible and the required files are available on it. However, ansible is not able to access this source directory probably due to its weird backslash escape mechanism. I'm getting the following output:

```
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
fatal: [192.168.195.131]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "dest": "C:\\Install\\available",
    "msg": "\\\\192.168.195.130\\share\\builds does not exist!",
    "purge": false,
    "recurse": false,
    "src": "\\\\192.168.195.130\\share\\builds"
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
192.168.195.131            : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I'm using WinRM. Anybody familiar with this who can please point me in right direction?

So far I've tried removing the single quotes around the path, adding double quotes, nothing works. Couldn't find a lot of information about this either. On the ansible docs, in the example section, there is an example which copies data from a remote shared folder and it doesn't have any quotes. Unfortunately that doesn't work as well.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_robocopy_module.html

Comment: The source path is fine, you can omit the single quotes. What happens, if you omit the `become_flags`?

Comment: @stackprotector Thanks for the suggestion, I figured out the issue and have posted the answer. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out. I was using the wrong user details in the inventory. The become flags are still required. So for anyone facing a similar issue, check the username/password combination for the ansible_user and ansible_password in the inventory and make sure that this user has access to the remote shared directory.